# Whats the use of EOSLIB_SERIALIZE?

Tags: eosio-code, c++

I understand that it is used for serialization and deserialization of a struct but why does anybody want to serialize/deserialize the struct? What's the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOSLIB_SERIAlIZE is a `DataStream Seralizater` , if you want to deep dive into what it does you should go to `contracts/eosiolib/serialize.hpp` in your EOS directory. It basically gives the struct extra operators for the `serialization` and `deserialization` of data to and from the `multi_index database`.

if you go deep inside this you  will found that it was using `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` macro. If you want to know more on `Boost preprocessor + enums` that is what exactly happening here you should go [here](https://www.smork.info/blog/2011/08/09/entry110809-105615.html) and personally I would suggest you to go explore more about enums in c++.

Comment: Knowing the "how" will not result in understanding the "why."  While more details around what the EOSLIB_SERIALIZE macro is doing under the hood is great, OP asked for the use case.